# Loading Classes without Composer (Autoloader) - Not found

Tags: php, class, autoloader

I'm not able to use composer so I have to do it in a different way, initially I used require_once to load every individual class but that didn't work out either so now I'm using an autoloader instead but I still face the same or similar problems:

The page where it starts:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

require __DIR__ . '/ERC20/autoload.php';
use ERC20\ERC20;
use ERC20\EthereumRPC;
$geth = new EthereumRPC('127.0.0.1', 8545);
```

This is the autoload file:

```
<?php
spl_autoload_register(function($class){

    $path = __DIR__ . '/' . $class . '.php';

    if(file_exists($path))
        require $path;
});
?>
```

The classes are stored in a folder named ERC20 that's in the same directory as the Client account php file.

This is the error it throws:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'ERC20\EthereumRPC' not found in
>   /home/sewicumg/public_html/contenthourlies.com/wp-content/themes/seoexp/account_client.php:35

Line 35 is this line:

```
$geth = new EthereumRPC('127.0.0.1', 8545);
```

The file EthereumRPC.php is present in the folder ERC20, and I'm using PHP7.1

Someone suggested to use an autoloader so that's what I did but to no avail thus far.

Comment: attach var_dump($path)

Comment: string(99) "/home/sewicumg/public_html/contenthourlies.com/wp-content/themes/seoexp/ERC20/ERC20\EthereumRPC.php"

Comment: I also removed the two use lines: use ERC20\ERC20;
use ERC20\EthereumRPC;, that way it does print the correct path, but I still end up with the error that the class can't be found.

Comment: Can you show us how the namespace is defined in your ethereum class?

Comment: string(93) "/home/sewicumg/public_html/contenthourlies.com/wp-content/themes/seoexp/ERC20/EthereumRPC.php" 
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'EthereumRPC' not found in /home/sewicumg/public_html/contenthourlies.com/wp-content/themes/seoexp/account_client.php:34 Stack trace: #0 /home/sewicumg/public_html/contenthourlies.com/wp-includes/template-loader.php(74): include() #1 /home/sewicumg/public_html/contenthourlies.com/wp-blog-header.php(19): require_once('/home/sewicumg/...')

Comment: This is the namespace in the EthereumRPC.php file: namespace ERC20;

use ERC20\API\Eth;
use ERC20\API\Personal;
use ERC20\Contracts\Constructor;
use ERC20\Exception\ConnectionException;
use ERC20\Exception\GethException;
use ERC20\Exception\ResponseException;
use ERC20\Request;
use ERC20\Response\JSONResponse;

Comment: I just created another folder named vendor, put autoload.php in it, as well as the folder ERC20 wih all the classes, and now the first error is gone. I also used a complete different auto loader file this time.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you have already solved your problem by some other means. However I thought I could add something as well.

afaik, when you use `spl_autoload_register` with namespace, you get the class name along with the namespace.

That's the reason why you got the following when you printed the `$path`:

/home/sewicumg/public_html/contenthourlies.com/wp-content/themes/seoexp/ERC2/**ERC20\EthereumRPC.php**

You see the namespace in the bold part above.

Therefore it is a good reason to maintain a folder structure that matches with your namespaces. Instead of creating a vendor directory and creating a new autolader, you could have just modified your folder structure to match your namespaces. That would give you a nice folder structure that's easier to maintain as well.

So in your case, to solve it, you could do something like this:

Let's say you had this folder structure initially;

```
.
├── ERC20
│   ├── autoload.php
│   └── EthereumRPC.php
└── index.php
```

Now when you use the autoloader, it receives the class name as `ERC20\EthereumRPC.php`  (and fails loading it, obviously). So instead of this, I will create a folder called `classes` and will put all my class files there in relevant folders (to match their namespaces).

```
.
├── classes
│   ├── autoload.php
│   └── ERC20
│       └── EthereumRPC.php
└── index.php
```

Then I would slightly modify my `index.php` file and `autoload.php` files as below:

**index.php**

```
require __DIR__ . '/classes/autoload.php';
```

**autoload.php**

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {

    $class = str_replace("\\", DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $class);
    $path = __DIR__ . '/' . $class . '.php';

    if (file_exists($path)) {
        require $path;
    }
});
```

Here the only difference is that I replaced the backlash in namespace with the `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`.

That's it and this should work fine :) I hope it helps. Feel free to ask if you have any doubts!

Comment: Thanks, but I'm glad this part is done after Googling for two days, and trying all kind of solutions. Now the hext problem but that's for another thread and messing around myself first for another day. I know very little about PHP but usually enough to get things done, but this library thing, and the new JSON header issue I run into is something completely different :)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by creating a new folder named `Vendor`, moved the `ERC20` folder in that folder and moved the `autoload.php` there as well.

I also used a different autoload that I found on Youtube, and now all the classes get loaded without error.

This is the the autoload code:

```
<?php

spl_autoload_register(function($class){

    $prefix = 'ERC20\\';
    $length = strlen($prefix);
    $path = __DIR__ . '/ERC20/';

    if (strncmp($prefix, $class, $length) !==0) {
        return;
    }

    $relative_class = substr($class, $length); 
    $file = $path . str_replace ('\\', '/', $relative_class) . '.php';

    if(file_exists($file)) {
        require $file;
    }
});

?>
```

And this is how I call the autoload file in the page:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this for creating a more permanent, elegant solution, given that you had already corrected the issue, in hopes that it does not become a recurring issue for you.

First, take a look at [the example autoloaders from the PSR-4 spec](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-4-autoloader-examples.md). You will note that in both the closure based autoloader as well as the class based autoloader, they both start with a *permanent relative reference to the application folder* (which is *hard coded in the closure relative to its declaration*, and *manually passed in in the class example*), and expand the vendor/package pair to originate from a subsequently named folder pair *relative to the application folder*.

This means you need to do a couple of things:

1) Declare a fixed constant, representing the path to your application root or vendor directory *in the first file that loads*.

```
define('VENDOR_DIR', __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'vendor' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

2) Manually include your autoloader declaration file and initialize the autoloader. If for example you were using the class from the [PSR-4 spec](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-4-autoloader-examples.md), then you would do so as such:

include **DIR** . '/path/to/autoloader.php';
  $autoloader = new \Psr4AutoloaderClass();
  $autoloader->register();

3) Next you would loop through your required packages and register them individually:

```
foreach (glob(VENDOR_DIR, GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $vendor)
{
    // Remaining valid directories are your vendor scope, by psr-4 spec
    foreach (glob($vendor, GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $package)
    {
        // This is your package scope, which needs to be contencated with the vendor name to create the base package namespace
        $pkg = $vendor . '\\' . $package;
        $path = VENDOR_DIR . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR // The relative path from the first file
            . $vendor . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR      // The vendor scope
            . $package . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;    // The package scope
        // Register the package
        $autoloader->addNamespace($pkg, $path);
}

// That's all, you're done.
```

Your directory structure should be something like the following:

```
root
|-index.php
|-vendor
  |
  |-vendor_name
    |
    |-package_name
```